# use @@SPID in side view defination in sybase ASE15

Tags: sap-ase

i am not able to use @@spid inside view defination.sybase doesnot allow.
how can i implement it inside view?. my requirement is: i have one table already existing in production server named MYTABLE. which have only one record at .so any select query form this table will give same output. now i  want to create a table based on ip address corresponding value will be defines. and want to drop table MYTABLE and create a VIEW with the same name
where it will use ip address to show corresponding output to based on ip address.
can anybody have idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
create view your_view as
select spid from master..sysprocesses
where hostname = 'HOSTNAME'
```

Comment: i don't want   to hardcode any value inside view e.g. hostname ,because for different host ,view definition should give different result. i want  alternative of below query                                                          create view MYVIEW
as 
select col1,col2 from TABLE1 where ipaddr in (select ipaddr from sysprocesses where spid=@@spid)

Comment: ah , we can use select host_name() for hostname

Comment: @deepak Did `host_name()` help?